# can we use multiple RegisterTransitCallback in ortools?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

Does anyone know if we can use multiple RegisterTransitCallback for different dimensions in ortools vrp?
What I have noticed in my code shows that only the last RegisterTransitCallback will take effect for all the added dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I is common to have one callback for time and one for distance. This is shown in vrptw examples.

So yes.

Comment: hi Laurent, thanks for the reply! 
In the vrptw example, I only found 1 RegisterTransitCallback which was used for the time dimension. (../optimization/routing/vrptw)

do u know any example for concurrent use of 2 RegisterTransitCallback? 

My use case is using time matrix as the main matrix lookup for register transit callback and for certain vehicles, it will have different additional costs for the different nodes it goes (another matrix lookup table) for the solver to consider. 
I'm still very new in ortools and not sure if there is any other better way to achieve the same purpose.